# Circular arrangement for twin pairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question: Say, there is n number of twins. How many ways can they be seated at a round table if k pair of twins has to sit together?

Solution: I solved it in the following way. Is it correct?

If I subtract k pairs from 2n, total no. of people= 2n-k. This (2n-k) can be arranged in (2n-k-1)! ways.

Again k no. of pairs can be arranged in 2^k ways among themselves. So, total no. of ways= (2n-k-1)! * 2^k

Comment: why are you subtracting 1? also, you have to account for the table being round

Comment: as for circular arrangement, n objects can be arranged in (n-1)! ways

Comment: ahhh, I see. I think that's right then.

Comment: If you subtract $k$ pairs, you have $2n - 2k$ people left.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $k$ pairs of twins sit together.  Do you mean exactly $k$ pairs? $k$ particular pairs? at least $k$ pairs?

Comment: @N.F. Taussing exactly k pairs

Comment: @N.F.Taussig and as k pairs, don't we take k no. of objects/persons, and subtract k, instead of 2k?

Comment: A pair contains two objects.  Therefore, $k$ pairs of twins contain $2k$ people, which is why you need to subtract $2k$.